# how to paste the content from clipboard in vue

Tags: vuejs2, clipboard

In a Vue app I have the need to click a button and paste the content, i looked around only to find the paste event like

```
<textarea name="myField" @paste="onPaste"></textarea>
```

but that is not what I want, what I really need is something like

```
   <button @click="paste"> paste </button>
   function paste(){
       let content = clipboard // but how would I get access to clipboard

   }
```

Comment: This is not necessarily specific to Vue. Clipboard access is usually done (now days, at least) via the `navigator.clipboard` API, which is a plain old JS API. However, VueUse provides a handy [`useClipboard` function](https://vueuse.org/core/useclipboard/).

Answer (score 1):

This may be a simple solution.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea ref="textArea"></textarea>
    <button @click="pasteToTextArea">Paste from your clipboard</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    pasteToTextArea() {
      navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
        this.$refs.textArea.value = text;
      });
    },
  };
```

You can also read more from [Accessing the clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#accessing_the_clipboard).